# data dateTime to only date to draw line chart

Tags: javascript, asp.net, sql-server

i want to draw line chart but my date get value including time from sql-server data
how can i remove time

```
            console.log(json);
            if (json.length > 0) {

                var datagraph = [];
                datagraph.push(['Date', 'Point']);
                for (i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
                    var smalldata = [];
                    var date = json[i].Date;
                    var point = json[i].Point;
                    smalldata.push(date, point);
                    datagraph.push(smalldata);

                }                
            }
```

console.log(json) 
here is the result

```
0: {DateTime: "2019-05-31T00:00:00", Point: 1}
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the function 'split' to divide the string by the character 'T'

```
let parts = json[i].Date.split('T');
let date = parts[0];
```